# Switching between Pinescript signals

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

There is an issue that I need your help on. I would be very happy if you could help me on this issue. I have not been able to solve this problem for a long time.

I have a project I am working on pinescript v5 and I cannot fix the input and output setting in this project. I want to explain this to you with a short example.

I get the long and short signals and open the position, there is no problem here.

But the long signal must first close the open transaction and enter the long, in the same way, in the short signal, first close the long and then enter the short, I think I can succeed?

example:
long signal
Close the short position then enter the long
short signal
Close the long position then enter the short

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this. Thank you in advance.

```
// Go long
if longCondition 
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_long, comment = "Long")

// Go Short

if shortCondition 
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_short, comment = "Short")
```

The original code I shared above. When I asked some people about this, they told me to use the code I shared below, but it was not a solution for me because to give the first example.
"In the long signal, first close the short position and then open the long position"
same in short signal

```
// Go long

if long 
    strategy.close(id='Short',   alert_message=i_alert_txt_exit_TP_short, comment='Long Signal\nClose Short')

    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long,   alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_long, comment = "Long")

   

// Go Short 
if short 
    strategy.close(id='Long', alert_message=i_alert_txt_exit_TP_long, comment='Short Signal\nClose Long')
 
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short,  alert_message=i_alert_txt_entry_short, comment = "Short")
```

example:
long signal
Close the short position then enter the long
short signal
Close the long position then enter the short

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6yPk.png)

Comment: What's wrong with the second example? I don't get it sorry.

Comment: I would like to explain the error right away. Normally, when the long position is open, when the short signal comes, it must first close the long position and then enter the short position. But the signals can be mixed, unfortunately, first the short input alarm is triggered, then the long output alarm is triggered. In reverse trade, as you can see in this example valid picture, most of the trades went right, but then when the position is open, it opens the reverse position and then closes the old position.

Comment: What happens if you send two commands in one alert message? So, your `strategy.entry` alert message will have two commands. 1) Close short (if you are already in a short position) 2) Open long

Comment: Yes, what you said is very true and that's exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, in the bot system I use, when there is an error in this way, the system performs wrong operations because it wants the open transaction to be closed without entering a transaction, then it wants to enter a new transaction, but when this happens, unfortunately, I encounter an error.